# Read Multiple Text Files based on dated name and write all to concatenate string

Tags: php, string, file, concatenation

I am very new to PHP and stared learning this week and I'm stuck at this problem.

I have multiple text files with names based on dates. I need to read every file within a date range and concatenate the text together into one long string.

What I have so far:

Creates different dates as strings and writes to variable $datef:

```
while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
$datef="$date\n";
$date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
}
```

Variable $datef is used in dynamic file name:

```
$file = file_get_contents('idfilebuy'.$datef.'.txt');
$string = ???? (all files to variable $string as concatenate string??)
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `$file` has all the data you want?

Comment: There are multiple files each with a name like:     idfilebuy2015-03-14.txt;    idfilesell2015-03-13.txt; idfilesell2015-03-12.txt etc.

Comment: Here's the doc, http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php. Khaled's solution looks like it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code as you mentionned overwrite the content of $date variable at each iterations so when you run `$file = file_get_contents('idfilebuy'.$datef.'.txt');` $datedef on contain the last while iterations.

You need to retreive each file inside your while statement.

```
$string = '';
while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
    $datef="$date";
    $fileContent = file_get_contents('idfilebuy'.$datef.'.txt');
    $string .= $fileContent;
    $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
}
var_dump($string);
```

Comment: @JohnDown  If it is can you mark it as answered so it may help someone one day?

Comment: Yes I will. One note. I think  $datef="$date\n"; needs to be  $datef="$date"; or it will break the filename into two lines and return an error.